# Replace multiple strings in XML using a key->value pair in a CSV file

Tags: python, regex, xml, perl, csv

I have a dump from our application server which contains XML of multiple strings. I am interested in the userID, which is embedded in the XML tags and in the format of (lasfir1) as in the XML examples below:

```
<row>
  <string></string>
  <integer>2177</integer>
  <string>assignee =lasfir1 </string>
  <string>Firstname Lastname</string>
  <integer>10</integer>
  <string xsi:nil="true"/>
  <integer>450</integer>
</row>

<row>
  <string>#ffd600</string>
  <integer>2199</integer>
  <integer>23</integer>
  <integer>474</integer>
  <string>assignee</string>
  <string>lasfir1</string>
</row>

<row>
  <integer>1536</integer>
  <string>lasfir1</string>
  <integer>235</integer>
  <string>USER</string>
</row>

<row>
  <string>#ffd610</string>
  <integer>2200</integer>
  <integer>25</integer>
  <integer>464</integer>
  <string>assignee</string>
  <string>lisfar1</string>
</row>
```

The requirement is to convert the string "lasfir1" only into its equivalent Email ID, which are available in another CSV (text) file which has key->value pairing of the userID and Email ID:

```
FirstName.LastName@abc.com,lasfir1
FarstName.ListName@abc.com,lisfar1
LastName.FirstName@abc.com,firlas1
```

The XML may not always be the same, but the string will be the one to search for, not the pattern of what is ahead or behind it.

Is there some simple way to read the key->value pair (in the CSV file), check if the key (userID) exists in the XML file and then replace it with the 'value' (Email ID)

This is required for a set of 300+ userID and Email ID combinations, all of which might not be in the XML.

Comment: Are you looking for a programming language specific answer ? Please state the details of language, framework you are using for rest of the application?

Comment: I am not sure if this could be programming language specific, as there might be different solutions in different langs. I have tried with sed and perl, but it is a tedious process, as reading each value from the CSV and then searching in a 17M line file multiple times is very resource intensive.

Comment: there are 3 <string> tags from which we are not able to distinguish the id that you are mentioning.

Comment: @stack0114106 the userID field can come up anywhere in the file, and as I have mentioned, there is no particular pattern that I have been able to use to search, except use the string from the CSV file to find the string in the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Perl one liner solution:

```
$ cat gagneet.csv
FirstName.LastName@abc.com,lasfir1
FarstName.ListName@abc.com,lisfar1
LastName.FirstName@abc.com,firlas1

$ cat gagneet.xml
<row>
  <string></string>
  <integer>2177</integer>
  <string>assignee =lasfir1 </string>
  <string>Firstname Lastname</string>
  <integer>10</integer>
  <string xsi:nil="true"/>
  <integer>450</integer>
</row>

. . . . 
. . . . 

$ perl -ne 'BEGIN { %kv=map{chomp;(split(",",$_))[1,0] } qx(cat gagneet.csv) ; $content=qx(cat gagneet.xml);while($content=~/(<row>)(.*?)(<\/row>)/smg) { $xml=$2;forea
ch $y (keys %kv) { $xml=~s/${y}/$kv{$y}/gm; } print "$1$xml$3\n"; } exit } '
<row>
  <string></string>
  <integer>2177</integer>
  <string>assignee =FirstName.LastName@abc.com </string>
  <string>Firstname Lastname</string>
  <integer>10</integer>
  <string xsi:nil="true"/>
  <integer>450</integer>
</row>
<row>
  <string>#ffd600</string>
  <integer>2199</integer>
  <integer>23</integer>
  <integer>474</integer>
  <string>assignee</string>
  <string>FirstName.LastName@abc.com</string>
</row>
<row>
  <integer>1536</integer>
  <string>FirstName.LastName@abc.com</string>
  <integer>235</integer>
  <string>USER</string>
</row>
<row>
  <string>#ffd610</string>
  <integer>2200</integer>
  <integer>25</integer>
  <integer>464</integer>
  <string>assignee</string>
  <string>FarstName.ListName@abc.com</string>
</row>
```

If you want edit only between  tags, then

```
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN { %kv=map{chomp;(split(",",$_))[1,0] } qx(cat gagneet.csv) ; $content=qx(cat gagneet.xml);while($content=~/(<row>)(.*?)(<\/row>)/smg) { $xml=$2;forea
ch $y (keys %kv) { $xml=~s/<string>${y}<\/string>/<string>$kv{$y}<\/string>/gm; } print "$1$xml$3\n"; } exit } '
```

Comment: when I run this script, it gives me an error sometimes: "The specified path is invalid."  The command is: perl -ne 'BEGIN { %kv=map{chomp;(split(",",$_))[1,0] } qx(cat users.csv) ; $content=qx(cat entities_email.xml);while($content=~/(<row>)(.*?)(<\/row>)/smg) { $xml=$2;foreach $y (keys %kv) { $xml=~s/${y}/$kv{$y}/gm; } print "$1$xml$3\n"; } exit }, and both the files are available in the folder in which I am running the command. This is on a Windows10 command line.

Comment: can you share the sample xml

Comment: it is a 1.7GB file. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Created a script using Python3, which takes in the input as the CSV and the XML file and outputs an XML file with the changes. The command is:

```
python xml_converter.py –csvfile file.csv –xmlfile file.xml –outfile output_file.xml
```

Not totally optimized as I would want it to be and running on a single thread, and assumption is that the files are utf-8 encoded.

```
usage: Replace username to user email of a given xml file
       [-h] --csvfile CSVFILE --xmlfile XMLFILE --outfile OUTFILE

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --csvfile CSVFILE  csv file that provide user name and email pair
  --xmlfile XMLFILE  xml file that to be searched and replaced
  --outfile OUTFILE  output file name
```

The basic script is:

```
class XMLConvert:
    def __init__(self, csv, xml, out):
        self._csv = csv
        self._xml = xml
        self._out = out

        self._kv_dict = self.prepare_kv_dict()

    def prepare_kv_dict(self):
        with open(self._csv, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            result = dict()
            for row in reader:
                result[row[1]] = row[2]
        return result

    def convert(self):
        with open(self._xml, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for line in f:
                _line = self.convert_line(line)
                yield _line

    def convert_line(self, line):
        # self._kv_dict = {'lasfir1': 'First.Name@abc.com'}
        for k, v in self._kv_dict.items():
            if k.lower() in line:
                # print(line)
                return re.sub(r'{}'.format(k), v, line)
        return line

    def start(self):
        with open(self._out, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for line in self.convert():
                f.write(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_file, xml_file, out_file = parse_args()
    converter = XMLConvert(csv_file, xml_file, out_file)
    converter.start()
```

I am trying to add threads and modify it accordingly to optimize the running of it. If anyone has a better way then please do inform.

Comment: The script above just replaces the first instance of the "string", if there are more, then will need to modify it to run